# Problem with firebase function it is returned undefined value in a async function

Tags: typescript, firebase, asynchronous, google-cloud-functions

I am creating a function in firebase that calls other functions. This call is made asynchronously one by one. When I call the **"foreachhours()"** function it uses a loop to call another function called **"getfilterhours()"**. When I bring the data from **"getfilterhours()"**, when it is printed on screen it works correctly. But when I assign it to a variable it tells me that I need a promise, that's why there is the .then after the call. The problem is that when I return the Ddr data the result is either undefined or an empty [] array. What options do I have to return that value without it showing up with nothing?.

```
async function foreachhours(horasselected: any,key: any){
let ress: any[][]=[];
let Ddr: any[][]=[];
//differents queries, in english horas is equal to "hour"
await horasselected.forEach(async function(hora: { hora: any; }){
    await getfilterhours(hora.hora,key).then(function(res){
        res=[];
        ress.push(res);//res=[{horas:["6:00","9:00"]}]
    });
 //<----The problem is start here--->
 //expected value is [{horas:["6:00","9:00"]},{horas:["5:00","12:00"]}, 
 //{horas:["6:00","19:00"]}
    Ddr.push(ress);//undefined or[]
});
console.log(Ddr);//undefined or []
 return Ddr;//undefined or []
}
//Function to get especific values from a querie in firestore
async function getfilterhours(hora: any,key: any){
var db = admin.firestore();
var elementosaux: any[] = [];
var elementoselement;

await db.collection("pedidos_servicios").where("key","==",key)
    .where("horas","array-contains",hora).get().then(snapshot=>{
        snapshot.forEach(doc3=>{
           elementoselement = {
                "horas": doc3.data().horas
            }
            elementosaux = elementosaux.concat(elementoselement);
        });
    }).catch((e)=>console.log(e));         
return elementosaux;//elementosaux=[{horas:["6:00","9:00"]}]}
```

Thanks for your help!:)

Comment: I believe that the problem is that both your `return` are outside the `then()`, specially the one on `getfilterhours()`, that will definitely cause issues since you are returning a value that is only populated after the promise is resolved. try changing that and let me know if it works.

Comment: Has the solution offered above helped solve the issue you were facing?